SQLAlchemy: Testing concurrent insert while maintaining test isolation with pytest
I have a simple test case and I'm trying to get more familiar with SQLAlchemy and PSQL itself, I've read a lot on the topic and tried different solutions; but none worked.
I'm using PSQL as the database and I have a table Category that has a unique constraint on the 'name' column.
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "categories"
    allowed_filters: set[str] = {"id", "name"}

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        nullable=False, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now()
    )

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    customers: Mapped[List["Customer"]] = relationship(
        "Customer",
        back_populates="category"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Category name: {self.name}>"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Category) and self.name == other.name

I have a simple service that inserts the data in a transactional context:
class BaseService:
    def __init__(self, session: Optional[Union[Session, scoped_session]] = None):
        """A custom session can be passed or the default db.session will be used"""
        self._session = session or db.session


class CategoryService(BaseService):
    def create_category(self, payload: CategoryPayload) -> Category:
        self.check_duplicate_category(payload.name)
        new_category = Category(**payload.model_dump())
        
        with transaction(self._session):
            self._session.add(new_category)
            self._session.commit()
  
        return new_category

@contextmanager
def transaction(session: Session | scoped_session):
    session.begin_nested()  # Start a nested transaction (savepoint)
    
    try:
        yield  # Everything within this block is part of the transaction
        session.commit()  # Commit the changes if no errors occurred
    except IntegrityError as e:
        session.rollback()
        handle_integrity_error(e)
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()  # Rollback on any other exception
        raise

The goal is to test create_category function by executing it concurrently and make sure that only one record is inserted while the other throws UniqueConstraint error. At the same time in Pytest I want to rollback all changes made per test to maintain test isolation.
Testing 'create_category' on a single thread is straightforward, I can use a regular Session or scoped_session and wrap the entire test in an outer transaction to rollback.
something like this:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_connection():
    connection = _db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    yield connection

    if transaction.is_active:
        transaction.rollback()

    connection.close()
    
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def session(db_connection):
    """session"""
    session = ScopedSession(bind=db_connection)

    session.begin_nested()


    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def restart_savepoint(sess, transaction):
        if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
            sess.begin_nested()

    yield session
    session.close()

I'm struggling to cover my test scenario when trying to execute create_category in 2 separate threads in my Pytest test function.
def test_concurrent_category_creation(app, db_connection):
    def create_category_concurrent():
        with app.app_context():
            connection = _db.engine.connect()

            # 1. Passing new connection works but I'm unable to rollback after the test
            # 2. Passing the same db_connection form the fixture SOMETIMES works
            # and I can successfully rollback the entire transaction
            # (provided I pass in the session fixture into the test function)
            # and other times throws a warning (I know connections are not thread safe)
            session = ScopedSession(bind=connection) # tried with db_connection
            
            category_service = CategoryService(session)
            
            try:
                return category_service.create_category(
                    CategoryPayload(name="Test Category")
                )
            except Exception as e:
                return None
            finally:
                session.close()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(create_category_concurrent),
            executor.submit(create_category_concurrent)
        ]
        
        # Collect results
        results = [future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
        assert sum(1 for item in results if isinstance(item, Category)) == 1

The warnings I get from the comment on scenario 2 above is the following:
app/tests/functional/test_categories.py::test_concurrent_category_creation
  app/utils/db_utils.py:37: SAWarning: nested transaction already deassociated from connection
    session.rollback()  # Rollback on any other exception

app/tests/functional/test_categories.py::test_concurrent_category_creation
  app/utils/db_utils.py:34: SAWarning: transaction already deassociated from connection
    session.rollback()

Maybe I am missing an idea or maybe the way I'm thinking about this test is not correct, I tried searching everywhere for testing such scenario with no luck. Is pytest-asyncio of any help in this scenario? I haven't looked too much into it yet.
Note: I am seeding the database with initial data using factory boy on each test session. I know I can drop and recreate the tables per test run but preferably I would just want to rollback the transaction instead of create/drop.

I'm not sure that this is the right approach. Assuming the appropriate level of transaction isolation, rejecting duplicates on a uniquely constrained column is a property of the database, not your application. I would think it is enough to test that once a value is successfully inserted it cannot be inserted again, unless you have strong reasons to distrust your database engine.
